# Visual Studio C# app force reconnection to web server if the connectivity drops out

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have been working on this issues off and on for weeks. I hace a Visual Studio form view application that load a webpage on located on my server. What I would like is to have the application to reconnect and reload the web page if for whatever reason the connectivity drops out. The PC which runs the application is at a remote location so I am trying to force the application to reconnect.

At the moment I have a half working method but it does not always work. Is there a more robust way of writing the code below.

Many thanks in advance for your time.

My reconnect code:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace NaveX_Browser
{
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        if (!InternetExplorerBrowserEmulation.IsBrowserEmulationSet())
        {
            InternetExplorerBrowserEmulation.SetBrowserEmulationVersion();
        }

        InitializeComponent();
        Cursor.Hide();
    }

    private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        browser.DocumentTitleChanged += ValidateConnection;
    }

    private bool offline;
    private void ValidateConnection(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (offline)
            return;

        //if (browser.DocumentTitle == "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage" || browser.DocumentTitle == "Navigation Canceled" || browser.DocumentTitle == "This page can&rsquo;t be displayed" || browser.DocumentTitle == "Broadband Link - Error")
        if (browser.DocumentTitle != string.Empty)
        {
            offline = true;
            browser.Visible = false;
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(obj => WaitConnection());
            return;
        }

        browser.Visible = true;
    }

    private int countdown = 20;
    private void WaitConnection()
    {
        while (!Native.IsOnline("http://www.example.com"))
        {
            Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => { connectLbl.Text = String.Format(" Trying to connect ...[{0}]\n\nPlease check your Internet router\n\nNaveX Systems Limited", countdown--); }));
            if (countdown == 0)
                countdown = 20;
            Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
        }

        offline = false;
        Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() =>
            {
                browser.Refresh();
                browser.Visible = true;
                countdown = 20;
            }));
    }

    private void browser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
}

public class Native
{
    [DllImport("wininet.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool InternetCheckConnection(string lpszUrl, int dwFlags, int dwReserved);
    public static bool IsOnline(string url)
    {
        return InternetCheckConnection(url, 1, 0);
    }


}
}
```

Comment: cooms? I'm guessing that's a typo for comms, and further guessing that what you're trying to talk about is *connectivity*? I'd suggest you make an [edit] that clarifies this.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever  thanks for the comment, I have edited the post.